# Quail Rules UTF8 behaviour

Tags: character-encoding, input-method, utf-8, quail

I had inserted the following code in `.emacs`:

```
(quail-define-package "LaTeX-UTF-8" "TeX" "TeX")

(quail-defrule "α" ["\\alpha"])
```

what I want to do is the following: when I insert the character "α" (I remapped the keyboard so I can do easily) I would like to see it replaced by `\alpha`. As it is it doesn't work. However if I replace `α` by some other string it works. How can I do?

Comment: How precisely you insert the character "α"?

Comment: @Name I have a new mapping in my keabord using serverX capabilities. (I'm using Linux). It's an UTF8 character.

Comment: My guess is that you need to switch to your defined input method to have it work. You could use a hook that enables it in LaTeX buffers or something.

Comment: I activated my input method with `C-\ ` and `LaTeX-UTF-8`. It does not work. However if I substitute `α` with `aaa`, for instance, it does the substitution. So the problem must be with that unicode typed in the `.emacs` file. Am I right?

Comment: I doubt one can do it with quail. You can do it with `abbrev-mode` as `(define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table '(
    ("α" "\\alpha")
     ("β" "\\beta") 
    ))

(abbrev-mode 1)`.

Comment: Why emacs has different behavior with `à`, that it is able to substitute with quail and `α`?
I also tried abbrev mode but the problem is that if I type something without spaces like `αβ` it is not triggered. Can you suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately using quail to convert a character from beyond the Basic Latin and Latin-1 Supplement blocks (i.e. anything with a codepoint above 255) is not possible.

Firstly, the `quail-translation-keymap`, `quail-simple-translation-keymap` and `quail-conversion-keymap` (which are used depending on precisely which quail-based input method you use) are assigned only for characters with codepoints below 256 (see 
[here](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/9f56d04df40cac6767b7fbed89737ce9f03f5d80/lisp/international/quail.el#L283), 
[here](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/9f56d04df40cac6767b7fbed89737ce9f03f5d80/lisp/international/quail.el#L354) and 
[here](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/9f56d04df40cac6767b7fbed89737ce9f03f5d80/lisp/international/quail.el#L375), respectively).

Secondly, and more importantly, an `input-method-function` can only act on a single-byte characters (apart from the DEL character —
[source](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/9f56d04df40cac6767b7fbed89737ce9f03f5d80/src/keyboard.c#L11740)). Since the main underlying way quail works, is by setting the `input-method-function` to `quail-input-method` (see in the definition of `quail-activate`
[here](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/9f56d04df40cac6767b7fbed89737ce9f03f5d80/lisp/international/quail.el#L594)), quail can't easily deal with other input characters.

To be fair, the main point of quail and the like is to facilitate inputting non-ascii characters with a "standard" keyboard and your use-case doesn't usually come up.

## Solution without using quail

Define your own special minor mode map. For instance:

```el
(define-minor-mode convert-unicode-to-latex-mode
  "A minor mode to convert inserted Unicode characters into their
canonical LaTeX representation."
  :lighter " cutl"
  :keymap (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
            (define-key map (kbd "α")
              ;; ;; Just using the string is probably preferable to a lambda
              ;; (lambda () (interactive) (insert "\\alpha")) 
              "\\alpha") ;; As suggested by Basil, in the comments
            ;;  [...] define other keys
            map))
```

Alternatively, if you want to do this globally, just do:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "α") "\\alpha")
```

### Lookup character in an alist

This was intended as a workaround to using lambdas, when defining many mappings, but just using a macro (`(define-key map (kbd char) "latex_string")`) is preferable. The method relies on looking up the last entered character in an alist and inserting based on that. Kept here for completeness.

The looping over the alist with `dolist` could obviously be used with any of the methods (macro, lambda, lookup function).

```el
(defvar convert-unicode-to-latex-alist
  '(("α" . "\\alpha")
    ("β" . "\\beta"))
  "Alist of mappings from Unicode to LaTeX.

Used by `convert-unicode-to-latex--insert'.")

(defun convert-unicode-to-latex--insert ()
  "Insert LaTeX based on last entered Unicode character.

Looks up the character in `convert-unicode-to-latex-alist'."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((key (key-description (this-single-command-keys)))
         (mapping (assoc key convert-unicode-to-latex-alist)))
    (if mapping
        (insert (cdr mapping))
      (message "Character %s not found in alist" key))))

(define-minor-mode convert-unicode-to-latex-mode
  "A minor mode to convert inserted unicode characters into their
canonical LaTeX representation.

See `convert-unicode-to-latex-alist' and
`convert-unicode-to-latex--insert'."
  :lighter " cutl"
  :keymap (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
            (dolist (mapping convert-unicode-to-latex-alist)
              (let ((key (car mapping))
                    (latex (cdr mapping)))
                ;; (define-key map
                ;;   (kbd key) latex)
                (define-key map
                  (kbd key) #'convert-unicode-to-latex--insert)))
            map))
```

Comment: Thank you! The last thing: I did not understand what you said about `a special function that would lookup the last character in an alist ...`  Why should I need it?

Comment: If you were to define maps, say for all greek letters, you'd have 48 lines of the form: `(define-key map (kbd "α") #'(lambda () (interactive) (insert "\\alpha")))` which some might find unseemly. Instead you could define a function which looks up `(this-single-command-keys)` in an alist (where the the alist would be something like `(("α" . "\\alpha") [...])`) and inserts the corresponding value. It's an aesthetic difference—there are arguments for either approach (conciseness vs. explicitness/simplicity). If you're not bothered by the method in the answer, then you don't need anything more.

Comment: Could you give me an example of this more elegant way?

Comment: I've edited my answer to sketch out how the alternative method would work.

Comment: If you want, you can replace `(lambda () (interactive) (insert "string"))` with just `"string"`. See the docstring of `define-key`.

Comment: @Basil, that's far cleaner than either of my solutions! Thanks! I'll edit the answer accordingly. (Also, thanks for the edit!)